# What is the easiest way to compare dates?

Tags: python, datetime

So I have a text file with this format:

```
[2018-04-04 11:46:05.879927]c:\windows\addins\FXSEXT.ecf,[created date]2018-04-12 02:35:21,[modified date]2018-04-12 02:35:21,[access date]2018-04-12 02:35:21,[READ]True,[WRITE]True,[EXECUTED]True
[2018-04-05 15:46:15.336327]c:\windows\System32\AcGenral.dll,[created date]2018-09-23 04:14:27,[modified date]2018-08-09 12:13:19,[access date]2018-09-23 04:14:27,[READ]True,[WRITE]True,[EXECUTED]True
[2018-04-05 15:46:10.556427]c:\windows\SysWOW64\AcGenral.dll,[created date]2018-09-23 04:14:30,[modified date]2018-08-09 11:20:24,[access date]2018-09-23 04:14:30,[READ]True,[WRITE]True,[EXECUTED]True
[2018-04-05 12:46:12.596327]c:\windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-a..ence-mitigations-c3_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.112_none_edebf6774847bf6e\AcGenral.dll,[created date]2018-06-19 22:49:33,[modified date]2018-06-19 22:49:33,[access date]2018-06-19 22:49:33,[READ]True,[WRITE]True,[EXECUTED]True
[2019-04-02 15:46:12.596327]c:\windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-a..ence-mitigations-c3_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.165_none_edb8e7b9486d9728\AcGenral.dll,[created date]2018-08-06 06:10:19,[modified date]2018-07-06 16:53:16,[access date]2018-08-06 06:10:19,[READ]True,[WRITE]True,[EXECUTED]True
[2018-04-05 06:46:32.596327]c:\windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-a..ence-mitigations-c3_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.1_none_f1a4c5155b750465\AcGenral.dll,[created date]2018-04-12 02:34:40,[modified date]2018-06-19 22:53:10,[access date]2018-06-19 22:53:09,[READ]True,[WRITE]True,[EXECUTED]True
[2018-04-05 15:46:52.596327]c:\windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-a..ence-mitigations-c3_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.254_none_edc2b94148665f07\AcGenral.dll,[created date]2018-09-23 04:14:27,[modified date]2018-08-09 12:13:19,[access date]2018-09-23 04:14:27,[READ]True,[WRITE]True,[EXECUTED]True
[2018-04-01 13:46:12.798327]c:\windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-a..ence-mitigations-c3_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.112_none_f840a0c97ca88169\AcGenral.dll,[created date]2018-06-19 22:49:39,[modified date]2018-06-19 22:49:39,[access date]2018-06-19 22:49:39,[READ]True,[WRITE]True,[EXECUTED]True
[2018-04-05 15:46:12.431127]c:\windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-
```

And all I need to do is to get specific date and string to search.
And from this date I need to loop line by line inside my text file and return `True` is the given string is inside  the text file or `False` otherwise (I need to search only inside line that there date is after the given date, the text file is sorted)

So first I have this regex that parses the `datetime` in the beginning of every line:

`date` is the time that I need to search from...

```
count = 0
text_file = open(file, 'r')
lines = text_file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    maches = regex.findall('\[(.*?)\]', line)
    if len(maches) > 0:
        currentdate = maches[0]
        count = count + 1
        if currentdate > date:
            # here I know  that from here all the next lines dates are after the given date.
```

Then I need to loop over all the lines and check if the given date (the variable `date`) is before or after the current date.
If I found the line that the `datetime` is bigger than the given date I know the I nedd to search the string from this line.

So my question how to compare between 2 `datetime`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since timestamp in `text` is always at the start of each line, you could simply slice it rather than using regex.

```py
from datetime import datetime

file = 'text.txt'
search_date = '2018-04-04'
search_string = 'WOW'

text_file = open(file, 'r')
lines = text_file.readlines()
search_date = datetime.strptime(search_date, '%Y-%m-%d')            # Convert to datetime

for line in lines:
    date = line[1:27]                                               # Slice date from line
    date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')          # Convert to datetime
    if (date > search_date) and (search_string in line):
        print(line)
```

> For Python >= 3.7.0, you could use `datetime.fromisoformat()` instead of `datetime.strptime()`.
>
> `date = datetime.fromisoformat(date)`

Comment: If i am using datetime.fromisoformat(date) i dont need to specify the date format ?

Comment: The timestamps are already in ISO-8601 format, so no need to specify explicitly. [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49784038/7046003)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you're turning your regex matched string into a `datetime` object. But that should be easy enough given the datetime format. Check out the datetime module docs.

Once you parse a datetime object from the row, and assuming the date variable is already a datetime object, you can use the usual `>` operator to compare two datetime objects. The datetime class overloads all of the usual comparison operators so that's pretty standard.

Comment: Yes thats right i need to parse my string into datetime, i need to know to datetime format in advanced ?

Comment: From your example text it should be pretty straightforward to construct they format. https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior